# Custom form action to handle data inside a plugin

Tags: plugins, php, plugin-development, forms

This is a stupid question, but I don't have much experience in the wordpress development. If I have a custom form that need to interact with a custom plugin, how I can get the submitted user data inside the plugin, what is the correct action that I need to set in my form? I'm able to use the `admin-post.php` but I don't know if this will work also with plugin.

Answer (score 1):

admin-post.php is perfect for that.

You have to do three things:

## 1. Set action for your form to admin-post.php

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo admin_url('admin-post.php'); ?>">
```

## 2. Add hidden input with name=action

```
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="my_plugin_action" />
```

## 3. Register your callbacks for `admin_post_{$action}` and `admin_post_nopriv_{$action}`:

```
add_action( 'admin_post_my_plugin_action', 'my_form_processor' );
add_action( 'admin_post_nopriv_my_plugin_action', 'my_form_processor' );
function my_form_processor() {
    // your code that will process form data
}
```